# NGRX Effects / RXJS: Loop API Calls and Actions

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

The goal is to loop through an Array of IDs and for each ID make an API Call and dispatch an Action with the result.

My current idea:

```
someEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(someAction),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectIds)),
    switchMap(([_, ids]) => {
      return forkJoin(ids.map(id =>
        this.service.getData(id))).pipe(
        map(result => {
          return actionSuccess({result});
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(actionError({error}));
        })
      )
    })
  ));
```

This kinda works, but has 2 unwanted behaviours:

1. actionSuccess gets only dispatched once and with the result of all api calls as an array. I want one dispatch for each API Call.

Replacing forkJoin with merge triggers an action for each ID, but then the API Calls are no longer happening, so there has to be more to it.

2. forkJoin waits for all API Calls to finish and only then continues. I want to dispatch actionSuccess immediately after every time getData() finishes.

Comment: How did you solve this? I am having similar problem @JockelzF

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking how to dispatch actions looping through an array in the `effects` but, how about if, for example, let the component handle the looping operation, with that, you will be dispatching for each id a success action.

Component:

```js
loadCustomerById(): void {
  this.store.select(ClientSelectors.selectIds).subscribe((ids) => {
    if (ids.length) {
      for (const id of ids) {
       this.store.dispatch(ClientActions.loadCustomerById({ payload: id }));
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Effects:

```js
loadCustomerById$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(loadCustomerById),  
    // you already get the id from action
    // no need of withLastestFrom  
    mergeMap(({ payload: id }) => 
      this.service.getData(id).pipe(
        map((response) => ClientActions.loadCustomerByIdSuccess({ payload: response })),
        catchError((error) => of(ClientActions.loadCustomerByIdFail({ error })))
      )
    ) 
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use merge instead of forkJoin - for more info see https://timdeschryver.dev/snippets#multiple-service-calls-from-an-effect

```
refresh$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CustomerActions.refresh),
    exhaustMap(({ customerIds }) =>
      merge(
        ...ids.map((id) =>
          this.customersService.getCustomer(id).pipe(
            map(CustomerActions.getCustomerSuccess),
            catchError((err) =>
              of(CustomerActions.getCustomerFailed(id, err.message)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: The merge instead of forkJoin stops the api call from happening. I console.logged the result of the service within the map afterwards, and with merge I only get cold observables. So if I subscribe to them within the map, I get the API result, but that's obviously not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest converting the Observable of the Array into an Observable which emits all of the elements in the Array using `from`:

```js
someEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(someAction),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectIds)),
  switchMap(([_, ids]) => from(ids)),
  mergeMap(id => this.service.getData(id).pipe(
    map(result => actionSuccess({ result })),
    catchError(error => of(actionError({ error })))
  ))
));
```

Depending on the length of `ids`, however, this could very quickly become untenable, and it might be worth refactoring your backend to accept a batch call.